# JavaScript fading slideshow - image links

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

I have this simple slideshow in JavaScript:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
$('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
setInterval(function(){$('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 3000);
});
</script>
```

With the CSS:

```
<style>
body {font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;}

.fadein { position:relative; height:332px; width:500px; }
.fadein img { position:absolute; left:0; top:0; }
</style>
```

And HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="fadein">
<img src="">
<img src="">
<img src="">
</div>
</body>
```

I haven't figured out how to add links to the images that are slided. I tried to add an anchor tag in the body of the html page for each image like this `<a href=""><img src=""></a>`, but everything gets screwed up.

Please give me a solution on how to give external links to the images using JS.

Thank you.

Comment: Try wrapping up your <img> and <A> tag inside a <div> and slide the <div>

Comment: Did this and encountered a problem: After the first image loads and fades, the others are displayed very fast and then the slideshow ends. `$(function(){
 $('.fadein div:gt(0)').hide();
 setInterval(function(){$('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut().next('div').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 3000);
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question has been asked a while ago but will answer still since I had the same problem.

This is the working script:

```
$(function(){
$('.fadein a:gt(0)').hide();
setInterval(function(){$('.fadein :first').fadeOut().next('a').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 10000);
});
```

:first-child needs to be replaced with first since there are more then one child and the selector needs to be changed to a. The link can just be added to the div as below:

```
<div class="fadein">
<a href="http://link.com"><img src=""></a>
<a href="http://link2.com"><img src=""></a>
<a href="http://link3.com"><img src=""></a>
</div>
```

I am working with the same code so can say I tested this and it is working

Answer (score -1):

You could follow this implementation:

http://jsfiddle.net/fenderistic/sT4Me/

This uses jquery's `.click(function(){});` and it changes the `window.location.href` when an image is clicked. You could give each image an `id`, and change the location based off that, but that's your preference.

```
$('img').click(function(){

    window.location.href="google.com";

});
```

OR

You can throw an `onclick` event that changes the `window.location.href` from there. I.E.

`<img id="pic1" width=100px src="" onclick="window.location.href='google.com'"/>`

Comment: The first implementation doesn't work. I just get the "hand" pointer on every image but when I click, it doesn't take me anywhere. And I can't put a JS function in the html code at the moment.

Comment: @user3095550 When you click the image, it will only change the output window location - not your entire browser window.